# Office 2011 mac / Exchange contacts

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, mac, microsoft-office

We have Exchange 2010 SP2 running in our environment and a whole bunch of Mac office 2011 users.

Recently, we had a new hire start and two of the mac office 2011 users (OSX Lion) noticed he's not showing up when they search for him in the global address list. If you search within OWA or Office 2010 for Windows, he shows up. It's just the mac Office 2011 users.

Anyone have any idea why this might happen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you mean. If the user is a configured Exchange/AD user, they're going to be available in the GAL.

If you're saying that there are problems searching for the user within Office 2011, then that's more of a problem with the Macintosh client.
See: https://superuser.com/questions/212754/global-address-list-in-outlook-2011-for-mac

But the official word from Microsoft is that the [GAL is not searchable](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macoutlook/outlook-2011-gal-search-deficiency/52b707a0-6d25-4bc5-a308-49439c852279?page=1) as it was in Entourage. Autofill from the `To:` form still works, though.

You can also add a "Directory Service" account in Outlook 2011 and enter your LDAP information to get something closer.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize there was a difference between the autofill and the icon on the right side of the "TO" field when composing a new message. I had assumed the autofill functionality wasn't working.